# Tokenizer that splits up words with underscores in them but also retains a full version

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm implementing an Elasticsearch search for content that has filesnames in it, such as 
"golf_master_2009.xls". I'd like a tokenizer that splits this up into at least the following tokens: "golf", "master", "golf_master_2009.xml". Now I have to use wildcards (for example "*master*") if I want to search for it without specifying the full filename.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply differents analyzers using a multifield field.
See http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/mapping/multi-field-type.html

HTH

Comment: Can you explain a little bit please on this particular case. thx

Answer (score 0):

You can use your own analyzer with [keyword tokenizer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/keyword-tokenizer.html) and [word delimiter token filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/index-modules/analysis/word-delimiter-tokenfilter.html) (with options `generate_word_parts` and `preserve_original` set to `true`)